# Converting PMSM motor differential equation to difference equation/discrete-time implementation

Tags: code, nxp, pmsm, z-transform, discrete

I am researching about sensorless control of PMSM, and currently looking at how to implement the algorithm into code. From this link [Module 9: Position Observer (Part 2/2)](https://community.nxp.com/t5/Model-Based-Design-Toolbox-MBDT/Module-9-Position-Observer-Part-2-2/m-p/748340). I encountered the equations shown below:

[image: eq19]

How did the author come from above equation to the solution below? (from Eq. 17 to Eq.19), which solves for i_gamma, i_delta

[image: Eq18]

With SISO system I know we can use z transform to derive difference equation which can be implemented in code. However, as this appears to be a MIMO system, I don't know what theory and tool for solving s-domain to the discrete-time domain in this case.

I would greatly appreciate any explanation or references to related materials.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that converting those expressions from time domain to Z domain would be an unnecessary complication, since there are time dependent functions being multiplied by each other; for instance \$\omega_{\gamma\delta}(t)L_qi_\delta(t)\$. In this case, we know that fact: *Multiplications in time domain lead to convolution in Z domain and vice-versa*, what is:

$$x_1(n).x_2(n)\longleftrightarrow(\frac{1}{2\Pi j})[X1(Z)*X2(Z)]$$

In other hand, the desired result can be reached simply applying the numeric method of integration known as **Trapezoidal Rule** (notice that  Bilinear Transformation is based in this rule, too)  :

Consider the differential equation below:

$$\dot{y}=f(y,t)$$

Integrating it between \$t_k\$ and \$t_{k+1}\$:

$$y(t_{k+1})=y(t_k)+\int_{t_{k}}^{t_{k+1}}f(y(\tau),\tau)d\tau$$

Approximating the integral by trapezoids, as shown in the figure below:

[image]

$$\int_{t_{k}}^{t_{k+1}}f(y(\tau),\tau)d\tau=\frac{T_s}{2}\left[f(y(t_{k+1}), t_{k+1}) + f(y(t_k), t_k)\right]$$

Here, I've used \$T_s\$ rather than \$h\$ to stay according the question. Traditionally \$h = t_{k+1} - t_k\$ appears as the integration step (or the sample time).

Therefore:

$$y(t_{k+1})=y(t_k)+\frac{T_s}{2}\left[f(y(t_{k+1}), t_{k+1}) + f(y(t_k), t_k)\right] \qquad[1]$$

The equations shown in the figure below are that numbered as \$(18)\$ on link you've provided in question (also, \$R\$ was replaced by \$R_s\$):

[image]

Applying the method in \$[1]\$ with these two first-order differential equations:

$$
\begin{align}
i_\gamma(k+1)=i_\gamma(k)+\frac{T_s}{2L_d}\left[u_\gamma(k+1)- 
R_si_\gamma(k+1)+\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k+1)L_qi_\delta(k+1)+e_\gamma(k+1)+ \\
u_\gamma(k)-  R_si_\gamma(k)+\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k)L_qi_\delta(k)+e_\gamma(k)\right] \qquad[2]
\end{align}
$$

$$
\begin{align}
i_\delta(k+1)=i_\delta(k)+\frac{T_s}{2L_d}\left[u_\delta(k+1)- 
R_si_\delta(k+1)+\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k+1)L_qi_\gamma(k+1)+e_\delta(k+1)+ \\
u_\delta(k)- R_si_\delta(k)+\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k)L_qi_\gamma(k)+e_\delta(k)\right] \qquad[3]
\end{align}
$$

The variable \$i_\gamma(t_{k+1})\$ appear in both sides of \$[2]\$, and the variable \$i_\delta(t_{k+1})\$ appear in both sides of \$[3]\$, which are, the desired quantities itself, let's group it and divide the both sides of each equation with the corresponding results (also, replacing \$k+1\$ by \$k\$ and \$k\$ by \$k-1\$):

$$i_\gamma(k)= U_{gain}\left[ u_\gamma(k)+u_\gamma(k-1) \right] + W_{gain}\left[\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k)i_\delta(k)+\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k-1)i_\delta(k-1)\right] + E_{gain}\left[e_\gamma(k)+e_\gamma(k-1) \right]+ I_{gain}i_\gamma(k-1)$$

$$i_\delta(k)= U_{gain}\left[ u_\delta(k)+u_\delta(k-1) \right] - W_{gain}\left[\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k)i_\gamma(k)+\omega_{\gamma\delta}(k-1)i_\gamma(k-1)\right] - E_{gain}\left[e_\delta(k)+e_\delta(k-1) \right]+ I_{gain}i_\delta(k-1)$$

Where:

$$
\begin{cases}
I_{gain}=\frac{2L_d-T_sR_s}{2L_d+T_sR_s} \\
\\
U_{gain}=\frac{T_s}{2L_d+T_sR_s} \\
\\
W_{gain}=\frac{T_sL_q}{2L_d+T_sR_s} \\
\\
E_{gain}=\frac{T_s}{2L_d+T_sR_s}
\end{cases}
$$

**Notes**

- In simulations, the Trapezoidal Rule has a better result when compared with the Euler Method. The later can be unstable and often requires a very low \$T_s\$.
- For me, the \$W_{gain}\$ and \$E_{gain}\$ are preceded by negative signs in the expression for \$i_\delta(k+1)\$.
- That gains mentioned on the code from your reference, contain additional factors in order to use adequate ranges for the controller (in 14 bit fractional binary, I think).

Comment: Hi Hirceu. I would like to add more 1 question about the equation: In the part from Eq. 16 to Eq. 17. The first question of Eq. 16 why does the author convert ω_γδ*Lq*i_δ from s-domain to time-domain as ω_γδ(t)*Lq*iδ_(t) while it should be a convolution, am I mistaken?

Comment: @Dinh Thong: Although I am not aware of all the content of the link you mentioned, my statement about convolution stands. Also for the \$s\$ domain, there is a property for convolution in frequency (\$x_1(t)x_2(t)\longleftrightarrow \frac{1}{2\pi j}X_1(s)*X_2(s)\$) and another for convolution in time (\$x_1(t)*x_2(t)\longleftrightarrow X_1(s)X_2(s)\$) for the product of functions. I tried to give an answer that justified obtaining Equation 19 from Equation 17 and made sense. In any case, on the link you've provided, there is a comments section, you could contact author for specific details.

Answer (score 0):

Re-examining the problem, I came to a solution very similar to the previous ones:
[image]

Comment: Very grateful for your contributions and answers. Surely I will check it out!!